# Подтормаживание TableView при скроле

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

TableView берет ячейку из xib - файла, ячейка состоит из ImageView и четырех label
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

функции делегата и исходника TableView по шаблону...

Код заполнения:

```
cell.title = categorySelectArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("title") as! String
cell.venue = categorySelectArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("venue") as! String
cell.date = categorySelectArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("date") as! String
cell.min_price = "от \(categorySelectArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("min_price") as! String) руб."
cell.img.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

ничего особенно тяжелого по моему, хотя картинка грузится из инета

Заметные тормоза при скроле но в тоже время у владельца бд нативное приложение  работает на ура.
Хочу убрать фризы при скроле по возможности без сторонних библиотек

Comment: а если закомментировать получение картинки с сервера, проблема пропадет?

Comment: Зачем каждый раз делаешь картинку из даты?
Как ты грузишь картинку? В каком потоке? Кто такой владелец бд? Пробуй комментировать по кусочкам код заполнения. Как только перестанет тормозить, считай, нашел баг.

Comment: комментирование картинки ничего не дает, тормоза остаются, картинку я беру с сайта по прямой ссылке, сайт на мощном серваке и толстом канале, общем картинка не причем, картинку гружу не в потоке а в стандартном методе tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: УПС, был не прав , картинка тормозит, вернее ее постоянный даунлоад, просто забыл закоментить при проверке непосредственного скачивания , теперь вопрос только в том как изменить алгоритм, вижу пока только одно решение качать  все картинки сразу в массив и привязывать при кроле уже скачанные картинки, скролить должно быстро но память сожрет ойойой

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539460/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB-uitableview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: VAndrJ спасибо за ссылку, но это не мой случай , так как грузится много чего тяжелого, в итоге после запуска видим такую ерунду http://uploads.ru/NKsLR.png

Answer (score 1):

Докумеканый алгоритм жрет больше памяти (айфоны тянут)  но убирает фризы
Функция getimages выполняется во viewDidLoad

```
func getImages(){     
    for str_imgUrl in categorySelectArray {
               let imageStr = str_imgUrl.valueForKey("image") as! String

                let imageURL = "https:\(imageStr)"
                let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: imageURL)!
                let imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!
        imagesArray.addObject(imgData)    
    }
}
```

далее в методе tableView(....cellForRowAtIndexPath) картинки берутся из созданного массива скачанных картинок

cell.img.image = UIImage(data: imagesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSData)

Answer (score -2):

Писать на Swift, использовать xib и удивляться тормозам? Это как писать под iOS на Nokia 3310. Создавай прототипы ячеек в storyboard, от туда будем думать. Следует профилировать (Xcode Run -> Profile) систему через Time Profiler (Instruments) и посмотреть что сильно использует систему, исходя из этого, можно уже будет сказать в чем проблема. (Добавить скриншоты профилировщика в вопрос)

Comment: хм, странно что xib - ы это моветон, в новой книжке советуют использовать, профилирование использовал,  проблемный участок после 20 секунды, когда идет скролл, до 20 секунды где пики  - это парсинг и заполнение массива    скрин профилирования : http://uploads.ru/Yf9BC.png

Comment: все понял, нельзя грузить картинки каждый раз при пролистывании, меняю алгоритм

Comment: а можно подробнее про "Писать на Swift, использовать xib и удивляться тормозам?"