# Тормозит скрол UITableView после запуска приложения

Tags: swift, uitableview, scrollview

Тормозит скрол при первом запуске приложения. Если поскролить таблицу, то всё начинает работать плавно.
Можно ли "разогреть" кэш перед отображением?

заполнение таблицы:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let card = CardDeck.instance.deck[indexPath.row]

    let cellId = "CellId"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SpyfallTableViewCell


    cell!.cellLabel?.text = card.name
    cell!.cellView?.image = card.image
    cell!.cellViewFull?.image = card.image
    cell!.backgroundColor = card.backgroudColor

    print(card.name)

    return cell!

}
```

Comment: средствами ios9 этого сделать нельзя, если только будете сами заранее скачивать данные. В ios10 будет дополнительный набор функций, что то типа предсказания какие ячейки программе скоро понадобятся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не делайте так. В

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Просто отдавайте `cell`. А заполняйте данными асинхронно в

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Тогда не будет тормозить скролл `UITableView`, просто данные будут появляться с некоторой задержкой в случае чего-то тяжелого (а если просто текстом заполнить, то и не заметите)

Comment: Стало лучше, но проблема все равно сохраняется.
Если грузить картинки из интернета, то все хорошо работает, но в моем случае картинки уже загружены в Assets и тормоза сохраняются.
Может я неправильно понял

Comment: Реализация: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        let cell:SpyfallTableViewCell = cell as! SpyfallTableViewCell
        let card = CardDeck.instance.deck[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellLabel?.text = card.name
        cell.backgroundColor = card.backgroudColor
        
        let image: UIImage = card.image
            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.cellView?.image = image
            cell.cellViewFull?.image = image
            }
    }`

Comment: @MikhailSh.  Присваивание текста внесите в `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. Оберните это все в `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue...` для простейшего случая. И вот `let image: UIImage = card.image` лучше не хранить картинки в массиве, храните имена картинок. А затем `let image = UIImage(named: card.imageName)` и в `cell`

Comment: Делал как Вы говорите. На эмуляторе микро фризы почти незаменты, а вот на устройстве подлагивает. Как я понял данная проблема возникает при чтении картинок с утройства, потому что при загрузке из интернета картинки просто появляются с опозданием.